# Detail band cutted off in the middle and page size limit in Jasper

Tags: jasper-reports

I use Jasper 6.6 to create pdf A4 format.

I have two problems:

1) I have detail band cutted in the middle, the rest of the band being projected on the other page. Like if the limit size was reached. Though, there is still space available on the page. I tried to use all split type available for detail band and it does not change anything.

One guess: as you will see, I have conditional diplay of certain text (see "Dispositions facturation" content). My guess is that even if it's not displayed, it still occupy place in the detailBand. I don't know how to fix this. To note: I can't use frame because it projects my frame as one block on the subsequent page.

2) I don't know how to increase my detailband size (or page size). I read that the size was limited for bands. So I guess, I need to create other bands. Is there any other way?

**Here is my template JRXML :**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!-- Created with Jaspersoft Studio version 6.6.0.final using JasperReports Library version 6.6.0  -->
<jasperReport xmlns="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/xsd/jasperreport.xsd" name="revueDeCompte" pageWidth="595" pageHeight="842" columnWidth="511" leftMargin="42" rightMargin="42" topMargin="20" bottomMargin="20" uuid="e40ca3dd-a126-4201-ba2e-02fad2685c5a">
    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.data.defaultdataadapter" value="One Empty Record"/>
    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit." value="pixel"/>
    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.pageHeight" value="pixel"/>
    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.pageWidth" value="pixel"/>
    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.topMargin" value="pixel"/>
    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.bottomMargin" value="pixel"/>
    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.leftMargin" value="pixel"/>
    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.rightMargin" value="pixel"/>
    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.columnWidth" value="pixel"/>
    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.columnSpacing" value="pixel"/>
    <parameter name="logo" class="Object" isForPrompting="false">
        <parameterDescription><![CDATA[Logo de la société]]></parameterDescription>
    </parameter>
    <queryString>
        <![CDATA[]]>
    </queryString>
    <title>
        <band height="79" splitType="Immediate"/>
    </title>
    <pageHeader>
        <band height="50" splitType="Immediate"/>
    </pageHeader>
    <detail>
        <band height="96" splitType="Immediate">
            <staticText>
                <reportElement x="0" y="1" width="148" height="30" uuid="76987bd1-0e7e-44f6-a4ee-aa0783847905"/>
                <textElement textAlignment="Left" verticalAlignment="Middle">
                    <font size="14" isBold="true" isUnderline="true"/>
                </textElement>
                <text><![CDATA[REVUE DE COMPTE :]]></text>
            </staticText>
            <staticText>
                <reportElement x="0" y="31" width="110" height="18" uuid="13afa98d-e049-41d9-a6de-4fcb461d589b"/>
                <textElement>
                    <font size="12" isBold="true" isUnderline="true"/>
                </textElement>
                <text><![CDATA[Type : ]]></text>
            </staticText>
            <staticText>
                <reportElement x="0" y="52" width="110" height="18" uuid="9a6e28b4-e6e5-4f68-8e3d-e163a5610d5e"/>
                <textElement>
                    <font size="12" isBold="true" isUnderline="true"/>
                </textElement>
                <text><![CDATA[Responsable :]]></text>
            </staticText>
            <staticText>
                <reportElement x="0" y="73" width="110" height="18" uuid="05c1e5bc-093f-4a63-82fd-44faef979f62"/>
                <textElement>
                    <font size="12" isBold="true" isUnderline="true"/>
                </textElement>
                <text><![CDATA[Groupe :]]></text>
            </staticText>
        </band>
        <band height="555" splitType="Immediate">
            <staticText>
                <reportElement positionType="Float" x="10" y="43" width="140" height="18" uuid="d7d5535f-f538-4535-aaee-566ec690f97d"/>
                <textElement>
                    <font size="12" isBold="false" isUnderline="false"/>
                </textElement>
                <text><![CDATA[Fichier descriptif :]]></text>
            </staticText>
            <staticText>
                <reportElement positionType="Float" x="10" y="63" width="140" height="18" uuid="b0d26808-d829-49bb-ab7d-a46992abb6ff"/>
                <textElement>
                    <font size="12" isBold="false" isUnderline="false"/>
                </textElement>
                <text><![CDATA[Contrat cadre :]]></text>
            </staticText>
            <staticText>
                <reportElement positionType="Float" x="10" y="23" width="140" height="18" uuid="7fca0ca7-09e7-491e-9d7d-85bddb9bbefc"/>
                <textElement>
                    <font size="12" isBold="false" isUnderline="false"/>
                </textElement>
                <text><![CDATA[Onglet généralité :]]></text>
            </staticText>
            <staticText>
                <reportElement positionType="Float" x="0" y="2" width="200" height="18" uuid="a2a2787d-6685-442f-a630-08a0e9ee9a43"/>
                <textElement>
                    <font size="12" isBold="true" isUnderline="true"/>
                </textElement>
                <text><![CDATA[Fiche société client : ]]></text>
            </staticText>
            <staticText>
                <reportElement positionType="Float" x="10" y="83" width="140" height="18" uuid="dbe422df-12d8-42a9-aa3b-9d83df0f50f4"/>
                <textElement>
                    <font size="12" isBold="false" isUnderline="false"/>
                </textElement>
                <text><![CDATA[Entités client :]]></text>
            </staticText>
            <staticText>
                <reportElement positionType="Float" x="10" y="123" width="140" height="18" uuid="d9bb820b-402e-46e5-b624-6626be5bc81c"/>
                <textElement>
                    <font size="12" isBold="false" isUnderline="false"/>
                </textElement>
                <text><![CDATA[Dispositions facturation :]]></text>
            </staticText>
            <staticText>
                <reportElement positionType="Float" x="30" y="141" width="130" height="18" isRemoveLineWhenBlank="true" isPrintWhenDetailOverflows="true" uuid="28be9fae-fd4e-4156-9938-71c2f5884f85">
                    <printWhenExpression><![CDATA[false]]></printWhenExpression>
                </reportElement>
                <textElement>
                    <font size="10" isBold="false" isUnderline="false"/>
                </textElement>
                <text><![CDATA[TVA :]]></text>
            </staticText>
            <staticText>
                <reportElement positionType="Float" x="30" y="159" width="130" height="18" isRemoveLineWhenBlank="true" isPrintWhenDetailOverflows="true" uuid="14923714-00fe-4263-bffd-d81cf11f0ecf">
                    <printWhenExpression><![CDATA[false]]></printWhenExpression>
                </reportElement>
                <textElement>
                    <font size="10" isBold="false" isUnderline="false"/>
                </textElement>
                <text><![CDATA[Numéro comptable :]]></text>
            </staticText>
            <staticText>
                <reportElement positionType="Float" x="30" y="177" width="130" height="18" isRemoveLineWhenBlank="true" isPrintWhenDetailOverflows="true" uuid="8343a99d-8da3-436e-8ee7-d9b9b47eb5b7">
                    <printWhenExpression><![CDATA[false]]></printWhenExpression>
                </reportElement>
                <textElement>
                    <font size="10" isBold="false" isUnderline="false"/>
                </textElement>
                <text><![CDATA[Délai règlement :]]></text>
            </staticText>
            <staticText>
                <reportElement positionType="Float" x="30" y="195" width="130" height="18" isRemoveLineWhenBlank="true" isPrintWhenDetailOverflows="true" uuid="01e27294-8e0e-4645-bfd6-38b7870fb7fb">
                    <printWhenExpression><![CDATA[false]]></printWhenExpression>
                </reportElement>
                <textElement>
                    <font size="10" isBold="false" isUnderline="false"/>
                </textElement>
                <text><![CDATA[Conditions règlement :]]></text>
            </staticText>
            <staticText>
                <reportElement positionType="Float" x="30" y="213" width="130" height="18" isRemoveLineWhenBlank="true" isPrintWhenDetailOverflows="true" uuid="1a59cabe-8998-4ca7-af0f-e67dd8ef7a67">
                    <printWhenExpression><![CDATA[false]]></printWhenExpression>
                </reportElement>
                <textElement>
                    <font size="10" isBold="false" isUnderline="false"/>
                </textElement>
                <text><![CDATA[Type envoi facture :]]></text>
            </staticText>
            <staticText>
                <reportElement positionType="Float" x="30" y="231" width="130" height="18" isRemoveLineWhenBlank="true" isPrintWhenDetailOverflows="true" uuid="dc66bc38-2120-4b64-97cc-945e623bf2c2">
                    <printWhenExpression><![CDATA[false]]></printWhenExpression>
                </reportElement>
                <textElement>
                    <font size="10" isBold="false" isUnderline="false"/>
                </textElement>
                <text><![CDATA[Adresse facturation :]]></text>
            </staticText>
            <staticText>
                <reportElement positionType="Float" x="30" y="249" width="130" height="18" isRemoveLineWhenBlank="true" isPrintWhenDetailOverflows="true" uuid="9ba512ca-ef68-44c5-8e19-58e57e2d980d">
                    <printWhenExpression><![CDATA[false]]></printWhenExpression>
                </reportElement>
                <textElement>
                    <font size="10" isBold="false" isUnderline="false"/>
                </textElement>
                <text><![CDATA[Mails destinataires factures :]]></text>
            </staticText>
            <staticText>
                <reportElement positionType="Float" x="30" y="267" width="130" height="18" isRemoveLineWhenBlank="true" isPrintWhenDetailOverflows="true" uuid="c93554c7-e10e-4eaf-917b-c024ec204ddf">
                    <printWhenExpression><![CDATA[false]]></printWhenExpression>
                </reportElement>
                <textElement>
                    <font size="10" isBold="false" isUnderline="false"/>
                </textElement>
                <text><![CDATA[Mails copies factures :]]></text>
            </staticText>
            <staticText>
                <reportElement positionType="Float" x="30" y="285" width="130" height="18" isRemoveLineWhenBlank="true" isPrintWhenDetailOverflows="true" uuid="d0d6d749-a384-48b0-8649-25b544a8d6bf">
                    <printWhenExpression><![CDATA[false]]></printWhenExpression>
                </reportElement>
                <textElement>
                    <font size="10" isBold="false" isUnderline="false"/>
                </textElement>
                <text><![CDATA[Adresse envoi courrier :]]></text>
            </staticText>
            <staticText>
                <reportElement positionType="Float" x="30" y="303" width="130" height="18" isRemoveLineWhenBlank="true" isPrintWhenDetailOverflows="true" uuid="0b30dc0a-d562-4114-8f32-1b0a2dd26692">
                    <printWhenExpression><![CDATA[false]]></printWhenExpression>
                </reportElement>
                <textElement>
                    <font size="10" isBold="false" isUnderline="false"/>
                </textElement>
                <text><![CDATA[Pièces factures :]]></text>
            </staticText>
            <staticText>
                <reportElement positionType="Float" x="30" y="321" width="130" height="18" isRemoveLineWhenBlank="true" isPrintWhenDetailOverflows="true" uuid="7ef51faa-5beb-4f00-ae3c-c80a9aeb6e84">
                    <printWhenExpression><![CDATA[false]]></printWhenExpression>
                </reportElement>
                <textElement>
                    <font size="10" isBold="false" isUnderline="false"/>
                </textElement>
                <text><![CDATA[Titre facture :]]></text>
            </staticText>
            <staticText>
                <reportElement positionType="Float" x="30" y="339" width="130" height="18" isRemoveLineWhenBlank="true" isPrintWhenDetailOverflows="true" uuid="cc4afcff-67c1-4426-8455-fe909f421492">
                    <printWhenExpression><![CDATA[false]]></printWhenExpression>
                </reportElement>
                <textElement>
                    <font size="10" isBold="false" isUnderline="false"/>
                </textElement>
                <text><![CDATA[Commentaire tva facture :]]></text>
            </staticText>
            <staticText>
                <reportElement positionType="Float" x="30" y="357" width="130" height="18" isRemoveLineWhenBlank="true" isPrintWhenDetailOverflows="true" uuid="5cfb7ae1-3ef3-425e-b9ed-3e62187aefbb">
                    <printWhenExpression><![CDATA[false]]></printWhenExpression>
                </reportElement>
                <textElement>
                    <font size="10" isBold="false" isUnderline="false"/>
                </textElement>
                <text><![CDATA[Référence contrat cadre :]]></text>
            </staticText>
            <staticText>
                <reportElement positionType="Float" x="30" y="375" width="130" height="18" isRemoveLineWhenBlank="true" isPrintWhenDetailOverflows="true" uuid="cf7afd97-e009-4bf7-8a87-17c34198e8f8">
                    <printWhenExpression><![CDATA[false]]></printWhenExpression>
                </reportElement>
                <textElement>
                    <font size="10" isBold="false" isUnderline="false"/>
                </textElement>
                <text><![CDATA[Référence fournisseur TV :]]></text>
            </staticText>
            <staticText>
                <reportElement positionType="Float" x="30" y="393" width="130" height="18" isRemoveLineWhenBlank="true" isPrintWhenDetailOverflows="true" uuid="cbce1351-94c1-4fca-8382-bae70a80c551">
                    <printWhenExpression><![CDATA[false]]></printWhenExpression>
                </reportElement>
                <textElement>
                    <font size="10" isBold="false" isUnderline="false"/>
                </textElement>
                <text><![CDATA[Mails relance commande :]]></text>
            </staticText>
            <staticText>
                <reportElement positionType="Float" x="30" y="411" width="130" height="18" isRemoveLineWhenBlank="true" isPrintWhenDetailOverflows="true" uuid="6456e941-a4a5-40ae-8929-b4b2b3c6e0ab">
                    <printWhenExpression><![CDATA[false]]></printWhenExpression>
                </reportElement>
                <textElement>
                    <font size="10" isBold="false" isUnderline="false"/>
                </textElement>
                <text><![CDATA[Mails relance règlement :]]></text>
            </staticText>
            <staticText>
                <reportElement positionType="Float" x="0" y="429" width="200" height="18" uuid="50b8b039-07eb-4444-9149-d8e3b892196a"/>
                <textElement>
                    <font size="12" isBold="true" isUnderline="true"/>
                </textElement>
                <text><![CDATA[Fiche Contacts clients  ]]></text>
            </staticText>
            <staticText>
                <reportElement positionType="Float" x="10" y="447" width="140" height="18" isRemoveLineWhenBlank="true" uuid="b5c26cae-d87c-4e37-b309-e757495e56a7">
                    <printWhenExpression><![CDATA[true]]></printWhenExpression>
                </reportElement>
                <textElement>
                    <font size="12" isBold="false" isUnderline="false"/>
                </textElement>
                <text><![CDATA[Contacts dirigeants :]]></text>
            </staticText>
            <staticText>
                <reportElement positionType="Float" x="10" y="465" width="140" height="18" isRemoveLineWhenBlank="true" uuid="74b40a0b-fb21-4dc0-9945-352192be69f9"/>
                <textElement>
                    <font size="12" isBold="false" isUnderline="false"/>
                </textElement>
                <text><![CDATA[Managers d'entité :]]></text>
            </staticText>
            <staticText>
                <reportElement positionType="Float" x="10" y="501" width="140" height="18" isRemoveLineWhenBlank="true" uuid="f6da2091-98ef-4384-963b-7d9b69dc9ba2"/>
                <textElement>
                    <font size="12" isBold="false" isUnderline="false"/>
                </textElement>
                <text><![CDATA[Managers d'entité :]]></text>
            </staticText>
            <staticText>
                <reportElement positionType="Float" x="10" y="483" width="140" height="18" isRemoveLineWhenBlank="true" uuid="65038fa4-7e73-4554-8e91-cc9a85e89836">
                    <printWhenExpression><![CDATA[true]]></printWhenExpression>
                </reportElement>
                <textElement>
                    <font size="12" isBold="false" isUnderline="false"/>
                </textElement>
                <text><![CDATA[Contacts dirigeants :]]></text>
            </staticText>
            <staticText>
                <reportElement positionType="Float" x="10" y="537" width="140" height="18" isRemoveLineWhenBlank="true" uuid="dc759890-32a9-4d62-969a-18aa80437f53"/>
                <textElement>
                    <font size="12" isBold="false" isUnderline="false"/>
                </textElement>
                <text><![CDATA[Managers d'entité :]]></text>
            </staticText>
            <staticText>
                <reportElement positionType="Float" x="10" y="519" width="140" height="18" isRemoveLineWhenBlank="true" uuid="de0f6854-abbf-45a4-a642-8b17df1865c2">
                    <printWhenExpression><![CDATA[true]]></printWhenExpression>
                </reportElement>
                <textElement>
                    <font size="12" isBold="false" isUnderline="false"/>
                </textElement>
                <text><![CDATA[Contacts dirigeants :]]></text>
            </staticText>
        </band>
    </detail>
    <pageFooter>
        <band height="71" splitType="Immediate">
            <textField>
                <reportElement x="160" y="20" width="100" height="30" uuid="610924a5-4d05-4edc-bebf-a8abf14f274e"/>
                <textElement textAlignment="Right"/>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA["Page " + $V{PAGE_NUMBER}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <textField evaluationTime="Report">
                <reportElement x="260" y="20" width="100" height="30" uuid="5acae58f-ec6d-4074-b37a-4a1f0853f30b"/>
                <textElement textAlignment="Left"/>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[" sur " + $V{PAGE_NUMBER}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
        </band>
    </pageFooter>
</jasperReport>
```

**Here is what I want :**

[image]

**Here is what I get :**

[image]

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Ok the solution was not so complicated. Maybe it can be useful for other people, so I set the answer here:

There is no other choice than creating a new detail band and all detail band needs to be split type: stretch.

Here is the template:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!-- Created with Jaspersoft Studio version 6.6.0.final using JasperReports Library version 6.6.0  -->
<jasperReport xmlns="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/xsd/jasperreport.xsd" name="revueDeCompte" pageWidth="595" pageHeight="842" columnWidth="511" leftMargin="42" rightMargin="42" topMargin="20" bottomMargin="20" uuid="e40ca3dd-a126-4201-ba2e-02fad2685c5a">
    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.data.defaultdataadapter" value="One Empty Record"/>
    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit." value="pixel"/>
    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.pageHeight" value="pixel"/>
    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.pageWidth" value="pixel"/>
    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.topMargin" value="pixel"/>
    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.bottomMargin" value="pixel"/>
    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.leftMargin" value="pixel"/>
    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.rightMargin" value="pixel"/>
    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.columnWidth" value="pixel"/>
    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.columnSpacing" value="pixel"/>
    <parameter name="logo" class="Object" isForPrompting="false">
        <parameterDescription><![CDATA[Logo de la société]]></parameterDescription>
    </parameter>
    <queryString>
        <![CDATA[]]>
    </queryString>
    <title>
        <band height="79" splitType="Stretch"/>
    </title>
    <pageHeader>
        <band height="50" splitType="Stretch"/>
    </pageHeader>
    <detail>
        <band height="96" splitType="Stretch">
            <staticText>
                <reportElement x="0" y="1" width="148" height="30" uuid="76987bd1-0e7e-44f6-a4ee-aa0783847905"/>
                <textElement textAlignment="Left" verticalAlignment="Middle">
                    <font size="14" isBold="true" isUnderline="true"/>
                </textElement>
                <text><![CDATA[REVUE DE COMPTE :]]></text>
            </staticText>
            <staticText>
                <reportElement x="0" y="31" width="110" height="18" uuid="13afa98d-e049-41d9-a6de-4fcb461d589b"/>
                <textElement>
                    <font size="12" isBold="true" isUnderline="true"/>
                </textElement>
                <text><![CDATA[Type : ]]></text>
            </staticText>
            <staticText>
                <reportElement x="0" y="52" width="110" height="18" uuid="9a6e28b4-e6e5-4f68-8e3d-e163a5610d5e"/>
                <textElement>
                    <font size="12" isBold="true" isUnderline="true"/>
                </textElement>
                <text><![CDATA[Responsable :]]></text>
            </staticText>
            <staticText>
                <reportElement x="0" y="73" width="110" height="18" uuid="05c1e5bc-093f-4a63-82fd-44faef979f62"/>
                <textElement>
                    <font size="12" isBold="true" isUnderline="true"/>
                </textElement>
                <text><![CDATA[Groupe :]]></text>
            </staticText>
        </band>
        <band height="436" splitType="Stretch">
            <staticText>
                <reportElement positionType="Float" x="10" y="38" width="140" height="18" uuid="d7d5535f-f538-4535-aaee-566ec690f97d"/>
                <textElement>
                    <font size="12" isBold="false" isUnderline="false"/>
                </textElement>
                <text><![CDATA[Fichier descriptif :]]></text>
            </staticText>
            <staticText>
                <reportElement positionType="Float" x="10" y="56" width="140" height="18" uuid="b0d26808-d829-49bb-ab7d-a46992abb6ff"/>
                <textElement>
                    <font size="12" isBold="false" isUnderline="false"/>
                </textElement>
                <text><![CDATA[Contrat cadre :]]></text>
            </staticText>
            <staticText>
                <reportElement positionType="Float" x="10" y="20" width="140" height="18" uuid="7fca0ca7-09e7-491e-9d7d-85bddb9bbefc"/>
                <textElement>
                    <font size="12" isBold="false" isUnderline="false"/>
                </textElement>
                <text><![CDATA[Onglet généralité :]]></text>
            </staticText>
            <staticText>
                <reportElement positionType="Float" x="0" y="2" width="200" height="18" uuid="a2a2787d-6685-442f-a630-08a0e9ee9a43"/>
                <textElement>
                    <font size="12" isBold="true" isUnderline="true"/>
                </textElement>
                <text><![CDATA[Fiche société client : ]]></text>
            </staticText>
            <staticText>
                <reportElement positionType="Float" x="10" y="74" width="140" height="18" uuid="dbe422df-12d8-42a9-aa3b-9d83df0f50f4"/>
                <textElement>
                    <font size="12" isBold="false" isUnderline="false"/>
                </textElement>
                <text><![CDATA[Entités client :]]></text>
            </staticText>
            <staticText>
                <reportElement positionType="Float" x="10" y="92" width="140" height="18" uuid="d9bb820b-402e-46e5-b624-6626be5bc81c"/>
                <textElement>
                    <font size="12" isBold="false" isUnderline="false"/>
                </textElement>
                <text><![CDATA[Dispositions facturation :]]></text>
            </staticText>
            <staticText>
                <reportElement positionType="Float" x="30" y="146" width="140" height="18" isRemoveLineWhenBlank="true" isPrintWhenDetailOverflows="true" uuid="cb24a630-080b-43fc-b004-479dfb420bac">
                    <printWhenExpression><![CDATA[false]]></printWhenExpression>
                </reportElement>
                <textElement>
                    <font size="12" isBold="false" isUnderline="false"/>
                </textElement>
                <text><![CDATA[Contacts dirigeants :]]></text>
            </staticText>
            <staticText>
                <reportElement positionType="Float" x="30" y="182" width="140" height="18" isRemoveLineWhenBlank="true" isPrintWhenDetailOverflows="true" uuid="ba590a38-bd88-4bc6-aa80-aab3cc27f5bf">
                    <printWhenExpression><![CDATA[false]]></printWhenExpression>
                </reportElement>
                <textElement>
                    <font size="12" isBold="false" isUnderline="false"/>
                </textElement>
                <text><![CDATA[Contacts dirigeants :]]></text>
            </staticText>
            <staticText>
                <reportElement positionType="Float" x="30" y="110" width="140" height="18" isRemoveLineWhenBlank="true" isPrintWhenDetailOverflows="true" uuid="545ae1cd-71aa-47dd-b706-11f81a40090a">
                    <printWhenExpression><![CDATA[false]]></printWhenExpression>
                </reportElement>
                <textElement>
                    <font size="12" isBold="false" isUnderline="false"/>
                </textElement>
                <text><![CDATA[Contacts dirigeants :]]></text>
            </staticText>
            <staticText>
                <reportElement positionType="Float" x="30" y="164" width="140" height="18" isRemoveLineWhenBlank="true" isPrintWhenDetailOverflows="true" uuid="ecc48888-aa56-47f3-ad55-641600fdef95">
                    <printWhenExpression><![CDATA[false]]></printWhenExpression>
                </reportElement>
                <textElement>
                    <font size="12" isBold="false" isUnderline="false"/>
                </textElement>
                <text><![CDATA[Managers d'entité :]]></text>
            </staticText>
            <staticText>
                <reportElement positionType="Float" x="30" y="200" width="140" height="18" isRemoveLineWhenBlank="true" isPrintWhenDetailOverflows="true" uuid="62d6ee84-07a7-4f2b-ace4-60e89842628d">
                    <printWhenExpression><![CDATA[false]]></printWhenExpression>
                </reportElement>
                <textElement>
                    <font size="12" isBold="false" isUnderline="false"/>
                </textElement>
                <text><![CDATA[Managers d'entité :]]></text>
            </staticText>
            <staticText>
                <reportElement positionType="Float" x="30" y="128" width="140" height="18" isRemoveLineWhenBlank="true" isPrintWhenDetailOverflows="true" uuid="f1a012a3-83e6-4ef5-8a4a-93c0b1a0e826">
                    <printWhenExpression><![CDATA[false]]></printWhenExpression>
                </reportElement>
                <textElement>
                    <font size="12" isBold="false" isUnderline="false"/>
                </textElement>
                <text><![CDATA[Managers d'entité :]]></text>
            </staticText>
            <staticText>
                <reportElement positionType="Float" x="30" y="254" width="140" height="18" isRemoveLineWhenBlank="true" isPrintWhenDetailOverflows="true" uuid="0f430f85-285d-469f-ba3e-cb428a28c313">
                    <printWhenExpression><![CDATA[false]]></printWhenExpression>
                </reportElement>
                <textElement>
                    <font size="12" isBold="false" isUnderline="false"/>
                </textElement>
                <text><![CDATA[Contacts dirigeants :]]></text>
            </staticText>
            <staticText>
                <reportElement positionType="Float" x="30" y="272" width="140" height="18" isRemoveLineWhenBlank="true" isPrintWhenDetailOverflows="true" uuid="abdc3a56-2e94-40b2-a314-601553cfcea3">
                    <printWhenExpression><![CDATA[false]]></printWhenExpression>
                </reportElement>
                <textElement>
                    <font size="12" isBold="false" isUnderline="false"/>
                </textElement>
                <text><![CDATA[Managers d'entité :]]></text>
            </staticText>
            <staticText>
                <reportElement positionType="Float" x="30" y="236" width="140" height="18" isRemoveLineWhenBlank="true" isPrintWhenDetailOverflows="true" uuid="f48c03ac-41f5-44f4-9d1d-1a54d328a6b5">
                    <printWhenExpression><![CDATA[false]]></printWhenExpression>
                </reportElement>
                <textElement>
                    <font size="12" isBold="false" isUnderline="false"/>
                </textElement>
                <text><![CDATA[Managers d'entité :]]></text>
            </staticText>
            <staticText>
                <reportElement positionType="Float" x="30" y="218" width="140" height="18" isRemoveLineWhenBlank="true" isPrintWhenDetailOverflows="true" uuid="8bec3c3f-fbba-484a-b3b7-48ef38bd8ae2">
                    <printWhenExpression><![CDATA[false]]></printWhenExpression>
                </reportElement>
                <textElement>
                    <font size="12" isBold="false" isUnderline="false"/>
                </textElement>
                <text><![CDATA[Contacts dirigeants :]]></text>
            </staticText>
            <staticText>
                <reportElement positionType="Float" x="30" y="308" width="140" height="18" isRemoveLineWhenBlank="true" isPrintWhenDetailOverflows="true" uuid="6c0b3fe6-1fd5-46d2-8e58-a53b8b7a6e96">
                    <printWhenExpression><![CDATA[false]]></printWhenExpression>
                </reportElement>
                <textElement>
                    <font size="12" isBold="false" isUnderline="false"/>
                </textElement>
                <text><![CDATA[Managers d'entité :]]></text>
            </staticText>
            <staticText>
                <reportElement positionType="Float" x="30" y="290" width="140" height="18" isRemoveLineWhenBlank="true" isPrintWhenDetailOverflows="true" uuid="a94318ab-52cb-4507-aec1-678d649ff453">
                    <printWhenExpression><![CDATA[false]]></printWhenExpression>
                </reportElement>
                <textElement>
                    <font size="12" isBold="false" isUnderline="false"/>
                </textElement>
                <text><![CDATA[Contacts dirigeants :]]></text>
            </staticText>
            <staticText>
                <reportElement positionType="Float" x="30" y="362" width="140" height="18" isRemoveLineWhenBlank="true" isPrintWhenDetailOverflows="true" uuid="fc4c6535-da1b-4430-817d-a2d849df2aec">
                    <printWhenExpression><![CDATA[false]]></printWhenExpression>
                </reportElement>
                <textElement>
                    <font size="12" isBold="false" isUnderline="false"/>
                </textElement>
                <text><![CDATA[Contacts dirigeants :]]></text>
            </staticText>
            <staticText>
                <reportElement positionType="Float" x="30" y="380" width="140" height="18" isRemoveLineWhenBlank="true" isPrintWhenDetailOverflows="true" uuid="efdbe66e-f2a4-483c-bb3a-3c159638f55d">
                    <printWhenExpression><![CDATA[false]]></printWhenExpression>
                </reportElement>
                <textElement>
                    <font size="12" isBold="false" isUnderline="false"/>
                </textElement>
                <text><![CDATA[Managers d'entité :]]></text>
            </staticText>
            <staticText>
                <reportElement positionType="Float" x="30" y="344" width="140" height="18" isRemoveLineWhenBlank="true" isPrintWhenDetailOverflows="true" uuid="b72d8aca-0b80-49d7-bfdc-31cca6ba3adb">
                    <printWhenExpression><![CDATA[false]]></printWhenExpression>
                </reportElement>
                <textElement>
                    <font size="12" isBold="false" isUnderline="false"/>
                </textElement>
                <text><![CDATA[Managers d'entité :]]></text>
            </staticText>
            <staticText>
                <reportElement positionType="Float" x="30" y="326" width="140" height="18" isRemoveLineWhenBlank="true" isPrintWhenDetailOverflows="true" uuid="404d83b0-181e-4f3d-92d2-de97883a453c">
                    <printWhenExpression><![CDATA[false]]></printWhenExpression>
                </reportElement>
                <textElement>
                    <font size="12" isBold="false" isUnderline="false"/>
                </textElement>
                <text><![CDATA[Contacts dirigeants :]]></text>
            </staticText>
            <staticText>
                <reportElement positionType="Float" x="30" y="416" width="140" height="18" isRemoveLineWhenBlank="true" isPrintWhenDetailOverflows="true" uuid="1d4d766f-8def-4a76-b5b0-f5f6d5b52ae8">
                    <printWhenExpression><![CDATA[false]]></printWhenExpression>
                </reportElement>
                <textElement>
                    <font size="12" isBold="false" isUnderline="false"/>
                </textElement>
                <text><![CDATA[Managers d'entité :]]></text>
            </staticText>
            <staticText>
                <reportElement positionType="Float" x="30" y="398" width="140" height="18" isRemoveLineWhenBlank="true" isPrintWhenDetailOverflows="true" uuid="e1ac5fa8-e9e6-4329-af5f-bfe82c28542c">
                    <printWhenExpression><![CDATA[false]]></printWhenExpression>
                </reportElement>
                <textElement>
                    <font size="12" isBold="false" isUnderline="false"/>
                </textElement>
                <text><![CDATA[Contacts dirigeants :]]></text>
            </staticText>
        </band>
        <band height="424">
            <staticText>
                <reportElement positionType="Float" x="20" y="54" width="140" height="18" isRemoveLineWhenBlank="true" uuid="140855d7-da8a-47ec-9e44-133403204bc2">
                    <printWhenExpression><![CDATA[true]]></printWhenExpression>
                </reportElement>
                <textElement>
                    <font size="12" isBold="false" isUnderline="false"/>
                </textElement>
                <text><![CDATA[Contacts dirigeants :]]></text>
            </staticText>
            <staticText>
                <reportElement positionType="Float" x="20" y="90" width="140" height="18" isRemoveLineWhenBlank="true" uuid="145adb87-ba48-4369-b807-073087620333">
                    <printWhenExpression><![CDATA[true]]></printWhenExpression>
                </reportElement>
                <textElement>
                    <font size="12" isBold="false" isUnderline="false"/>
                </textElement>
                <text><![CDATA[Contacts dirigeants :]]></text>
            </staticText>
            <staticText>
                <reportElement positionType="Float" x="10" y="0" width="200" height="18" uuid="26964ed0-cac8-4c5d-8965-4207f14729b5"/>
                <textElement>
                    <font size="12" isBold="true" isUnderline="true"/>
                </textElement>
                <text><![CDATA[Fiche Contacts clients  ]]></text>
            </staticText>
            <staticText>
                <reportElement positionType="Float" x="20" y="18" width="140" height="18" isRemoveLineWhenBlank="true" uuid="ebc1cbcc-3f64-4b45-9a10-2dd4d32c59f9">
                    <printWhenExpression><![CDATA[true]]></printWhenExpression>
                </reportElement>
                <textElement>
                    <font size="12" isBold="false" isUnderline="false"/>
                </textElement>
                <text><![CDATA[Contacts dirigeants :]]></text>
            </staticText>
            <staticText>
                <reportElement positionType="Float" x="20" y="72" width="140" height="18" isRemoveLineWhenBlank="true" uuid="e63e1bf2-d4a1-4e2d-9bc4-431346315202"/>
                <textElement>
                    <font size="12" isBold="false" isUnderline="false"/>
                </textElement>
                <text><![CDATA[Managers d'entité :]]></text>
            </staticText>
            <staticText>
                <reportElement positionType="Float" x="20" y="108" width="140" height="18" isRemoveLineWhenBlank="true" uuid="34c46313-5d34-4bfc-93ee-987c730921f9"/>
                <textElement>
                    <font size="12" isBold="false" isUnderline="false"/>
                </textElement>
                <text><![CDATA[Managers d'entité :]]></text>
            </staticText>
            <staticText>
                <reportElement positionType="Float" x="20" y="36" width="140" height="18" isRemoveLineWhenBlank="true" uuid="469f7049-5c0a-4080-9b43-99abf81f83cf"/>
                <textElement>
                    <font size="12" isBold="false" isUnderline="false"/>
                </textElement>
                <text><![CDATA[Managers d'entité :]]></text>
            </staticText>
            <staticText>
                <reportElement positionType="Float" x="20" y="216" width="140" height="18" isRemoveLineWhenBlank="true" uuid="b8d5931f-6782-4c60-83d6-903a9a75d0f6"/>
                <textElement>
                    <font size="12" isBold="false" isUnderline="false"/>
                </textElement>
                <text><![CDATA[Managers d'entité :]]></text>
            </staticText>
            <staticText>
                <reportElement positionType="Float" x="20" y="126" width="140" height="18" isRemoveLineWhenBlank="true" uuid="f63a5f49-f043-46ef-a9d5-ca1c8dc669da">
                    <printWhenExpression><![CDATA[true]]></printWhenExpression>
                </reportElement>
                <textElement>
                    <font size="12" isBold="false" isUnderline="false"/>
                </textElement>
                <text><![CDATA[Contacts dirigeants :]]></text>
            </staticText>
            <staticText>
                <reportElement positionType="Float" x="20" y="180" width="140" height="18" isRemoveLineWhenBlank="true" uuid="b566e510-a0c5-468b-9a80-626cfd56c39c"/>
                <textElement>
                    <font size="12" isBold="false" isUnderline="false"/>
                </textElement>
                <text><![CDATA[Managers d'entité :]]></text>
            </staticText>
            <staticText>
                <reportElement positionType="Float" x="20" y="198" width="140" height="18" isRemoveLineWhenBlank="true" uuid="914c4c14-82aa-4640-9b4a-ddf00618f3f1">
                    <printWhenExpression><![CDATA[true]]></printWhenExpression>
                </reportElement>
                <textElement>
                    <font size="12" isBold="false" isUnderline="false"/>
                </textElement>
                <text><![CDATA[Contacts dirigeants :]]></text>
            </staticText>
            <staticText>
                <reportElement positionType="Float" x="20" y="162" width="140" height="18" isRemoveLineWhenBlank="true" uuid="1d6b78a1-721b-439e-bcc8-9d6e3f97c869">
                    <printWhenExpression><![CDATA[true]]></printWhenExpression>
                </reportElement>
                <textElement>
                    <font size="12" isBold="false" isUnderline="false"/>
                </textElement>
                <text><![CDATA[Contacts dirigeants :]]></text>
            </staticText>
            <staticText>
                <reportElement positionType="Float" x="20" y="144" width="140" height="18" isRemoveLineWhenBlank="true" uuid="f72203c8-036c-4865-8f2b-25abf9e1e214"/>
                <textElement>
                    <font size="12" isBold="false" isUnderline="false"/>
                </textElement>
                <text><![CDATA[Managers d'entité :]]></text>
            </staticText>
            <staticText>
                <reportElement positionType="Float" x="20" y="288" width="140" height="18" isRemoveLineWhenBlank="true" uuid="afe5f062-b6dc-4c06-bd2f-32adab9a0fca"/>
                <textElement>
                    <font size="12" isBold="false" isUnderline="false"/>
                </textElement>
                <text><![CDATA[Managers d'entité :]]></text>
            </staticText>
            <staticText>
                <reportElement positionType="Float" x="20" y="270" width="140" height="18" isRemoveLineWhenBlank="true" uuid="d9c6496c-d740-4642-a91c-29fe05c4ae21">
                    <printWhenExpression><![CDATA[true]]></printWhenExpression>
                </reportElement>
                <textElement>
                    <font size="12" isBold="false" isUnderline="false"/>
                </textElement>
                <text><![CDATA[Contacts dirigeants :]]></text>
            </staticText>
            <staticText>
                <reportElement positionType="Float" x="20" y="306" width="140" height="18" isRemoveLineWhenBlank="true" uuid="e39a47f6-f975-429a-be11-c0bc9a2d9329">
                    <printWhenExpression><![CDATA[true]]></printWhenExpression>
                </reportElement>
                <textElement>
                    <font size="12" isBold="false" isUnderline="false"/>
                </textElement>
                <text><![CDATA[Contacts dirigeants :]]></text>
            </staticText>
            <staticText>
                <reportElement positionType="Float" x="20" y="252" width="140" height="18" isRemoveLineWhenBlank="true" uuid="345d4f5d-c9eb-49d3-b82f-67a76323d157"/>
                <textElement>
                    <font size="12" isBold="false" isUnderline="false"/>
                </textElement>
                <text><![CDATA[Managers d'entité :]]></text>
            </staticText>
            <staticText>
                <reportElement positionType="Float" x="20" y="234" width="140" height="18" isRemoveLineWhenBlank="true" uuid="83de6c1e-00bb-40f7-bb39-745a116ffa24">
                    <printWhenExpression><![CDATA[true]]></printWhenExpression>
                </reportElement>
                <textElement>
                    <font size="12" isBold="false" isUnderline="false"/>
                </textElement>
                <text><![CDATA[Contacts dirigeants :]]></text>
            </staticText>
            <staticText>
                <reportElement positionType="Float" x="20" y="324" width="140" height="18" isRemoveLineWhenBlank="true" uuid="7fe4ed19-b2fa-4aea-8d9d-3c65575ada53"/>
                <textElement>
                    <font size="12" isBold="false" isUnderline="false"/>
                </textElement>
                <text><![CDATA[Managers d'entité :]]></text>
            </staticText>
        </band>
    </detail>
    <pageFooter>
        <band height="71" splitType="Immediate">
            <textField>
                <reportElement x="160" y="20" width="100" height="30" uuid="610924a5-4d05-4edc-bebf-a8abf14f274e"/>
                <textElement textAlignment="Right"/>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA["Page " + $V{PAGE_NUMBER}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <textField evaluationTime="Report">
                <reportElement x="260" y="20" width="100" height="30" uuid="5acae58f-ec6d-4074-b37a-4a1f0853f30b"/>
                <textElement textAlignment="Left"/>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[" sur " + $V{PAGE_NUMBER}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
        </band>
    </pageFooter>
</jasperReport>
```

Here is what I get:

[image]